# Optim function in R: Why do I have the optimization results as the initial values?

Tags: r, optimization, log-likelihood

I am a beginner in programming and here is my code. My goal is to maximize the likelihood function (BTdata$ll), but the optim function gives me the same values that I submitted at the beginning as initial values and I don't understand the reason.
Thanks in advance for your comments

```
init_param =c(-2.78575225,0.40203595,-0.37699998,-0.03953779,0.04939630,-0.18220220,
              -0.11168393,0.31706854,0.08217358,0.15622750,0.80859611,
              -12.11972795,-12.66410641,-10.84349371,-0.19092956,
              -1.24902402,0.22166385,0.19705884,-0.33505426,-0.21373610,-0.26286383)

init_param =as.numeric(init_param)
max.loglike.Poisson<- function(init_param,BTdata){                  
           BTdata$lambda <- exp(init_param[1]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='6')*init_param[2]
           +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='5')*init_param[3]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='4')*init_param[4]
           +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='2')*init_param[5]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='3')*init_param[6]
           +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='1')*init_param[7]+I(BTdata$MILEAGE=='1')*init_param[8]
           + I(BTdata$MILEAGE=='2')*init_param[9]+I(BTdata$MILEAGE=='4')*init_param[10]
           + offset(log(BTdata$EXPOSITION)))                                                                   

    BTdata$ki<-exp(init_param[11]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='6')*init_param[12]
      +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='5')*init_param[13]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='4')*init_param[14]
      +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='2')*init_param[15]+I(BTdata$AGE_A=='3')*init_param[16]
      +I(BTdata$AGE_A=='1')*init_param[17]+I(BTdata$GENDER=='1')*init_param[18]
      +I(BTdata$MarStatus=='1')*init_param[19]+I(BTdata$MarStatus=='2')*init_param[20]
      +BTdata$offset_reg*init_param[21])

       alpha= 1.5 # this is suppose to be the shape of gamma distribution
       BTdata$ll=log(gamma(BTdata$D+BTdata$NBC+alpha))
                 - log(gamma(BTdata$D+1))-log(gamma(BTdata$NBC+1))
                 - log(gamma(alpha))+alpha*log(alpha)+BTdata$NBC*log(BTdata$lambda)
                 + BTdata$D*log(BTdata$ki)-(alpha+BTdata$NBC+BTdata$D)*log(alpha
                 + BTdata$ki*BTdata$offset_reg+BTdata$lambda)
                   loglike <- sum(BTdata$ll)
                   return(-loglike) 
                    }
 real_Poisson<-optim(init_param, max.loglike.Poisson, data=BTdata,method="BFGS", control=list(maxit=50000),hessian=TRUE)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python` if the question is about `R`?

Comment: I read on google that R and Python are similaire.

Comment: This doesn't look at all like Python.

Comment: Spanish and French have some similarities, but they are very different languages. The same applies to programming languages as well.

Comment: `BTdata` is missing.  `I(...)` just returns its argument with a different class and is not needed.  `offset` just returns its argument and also isn't needed.

Comment: I called each variable by its name inside the function but I received an error message that the object is not found so I added Btdata$var and put all code inside max.loglike.Poisson .